# How do i change directory location for file in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i am trying to hide my directory location which contains files just to prevent users to know the location of that file. is that possible with url rewriting ? I have url to file like this.

```
http://example.com/directory-1/directory-2/directory-3/myfile.pdf
```

i am using this file in iframe for online viewing so this rewritten url also will be using in SRC of this iframe. please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `/.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /directory-1/directory-2/directory-3/$1.pdf [NC,L]
```

this will internally redirect

```
 http://example.com/myfile
```

to

```
    http://example.com/directory-1/directory-2/directory-3/file.pdf
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, unfortunately still i am unable to figure out perhaps my directory-1/directory-2/directory-3/ are dynamic directories that keep getting changed against each file. will this rule still work in this scenario ?